# Fetch data into datatables using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I am new to `laravel`. I want to fetch the data from database and put it to `datatable`. This is my html

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="th_days_client" >
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <i class="material-icons">flag</i>
                                    {{ $title }}
                                </h4>
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-up clickable"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times removepanel clickable"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="th_days_client_data" class="table table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Mobile</th>
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The `jQuery` for this is :

```
var th_days_client;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        th_days_client = $('#th_days_client_data').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],
            "columns":[
                {"data":"name"},
                {"data":"email"},
                {"data":"mobile"},
                {"data":"actions"}
            ],
            "ajax": "{{ url('client') }}" + ((typeof $('#th_days_client_data').attr('data-id') != "undefined") ? "/" + $('#id').val() + "/" + $('#th_days_client_data').attr('data-id') : "/th_days_client_data")
        });
    });
```

`controller Function` for this is :

```
public function th_days_client_data(Datatables $datatables)
{

   $clientObj = new Client;
    $client = $clientObj->get()
        ->map(function ($client) {
        return [
            'id' => $client->id,
            'name' => $client->first_name.' '.$client->last_name,
            'email' => $client->email,
            'mobile' => $client->mobile
        ];
    });

    return $datatables->collection($client)

        ->addColumn('actions', '@if(Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                <a href="{{ url(\'client/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}" title="{{ trans(\'table.edit\') }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil text-warning "></i> </a>
                                @endif
                                <a href="{{ url(\'client/\' . $id . \'/show\' ) }}" title="{{ trans(\'table.details\') }}" >
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye text-primary"></i> </a>
                                @if(Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteClient({{$id}})"  title="{{ trans(\'table.delete\') }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash text-danger"></i> </a>
                                   @endif')

        ->removeColumn('id')
        ->rawColumns(['actions'])->make();
}
```

When I am running this code then it is giving error :

```
DataTables warning: table id=th_days_client_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: And did you visit the URL mentioned?

Comment: Datatable id should be your table id : pending_client_data

Comment: yes i visited ..

Comment: @AmanKumar updated the table id but got the same error

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel ajax validate CSRF Token so add below code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Response status must be 2XX and
response data must be valid JSON
You should check it or attach response data to you question as well